# Force Close When Dynamically Creating Widget from XML in Android

Tags: java, android, casting, android-widget

I'm attempting to create a few radio buttons and add them a RadioGroup dynamically. When I use the LayoutInflater method of pulling in the xml and adding it to the current view, everything works fine. The correct radio buttons show up.

However when I try to cast the View that LayoutInflater.inflate returned to a RadioButton (so I can setText), I get a force close with a java.lang.ClassCastException.

```
for (int i = 0; i < options.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject option = options.getJSONObject(i);

  View option_view = vi.inflate(R.layout.poll_option, radio_group, true);
  option_view.setId(i);

  RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) option_view.findViewById(i);

  rb.setText(option.getString("response"));
}
```

poll_option.xml:

```
<RadioButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:text="RadioButton" 
             android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Can we see the poll_option.xml file that you are inflating?  Something isn't matching between what you have set in the XML document and your retrieval method in code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you're not getting the views you think you're getting.  `LayoutInflater.inflate()` called with a supplied root view means the view returned to you is THAT root view (not the inflated view).  The method in which you are calling it inflates a new RadioButton and attaches it to the Group, but the return value (option_view) is the group itself, not the individual item.  Since you need to play with the view before attaching it to the group, I'd recommend code like this (which works):

```
//I added these for posterity, I'm sure however you get these references is fine
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
RadioGroup radio_group = new RadioGroup(this);
//Get the button, rename it, then add it to the group.
for(int i = 0; i < options.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject option = options.getJSONObject(i);

    RadioButton option_view = (RadioButton)vi.inflate(R.layout.poll_option, null);
    option_view.setText(option.getString("response"));

    radio_group.addView(button);
}
```

**Editorial Note:**

Just my $0.02, for such a simple layout, running this inflation process over and over in a loop may be a bit too much (inflation is expensive).  You could easily create the same `RadioButton` in code, and add it with your LayoutParams, like:

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
for (int i = 0; i < options.length(); i++) {
    RadioButton option_view = new RadioButton(this);
    option_view.setText(option.getString("response"));
    radio_group.addView(option_view, params);
}
```

This code I didn't test, but it should be pretty close :p

Hope that Helps!

Comment: I didn't try the first method, but the second works perfectly. I don't anticipate this needing to be much more complex, so it will do. Thanks for taking your time to write (and apparently test) this code.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `findViewById` and locate the radio button in the inflated view. Something like:

`RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)option_view.findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId);`

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)

Comment: Well I'm running this in a loop, so there is an unknown number of RadioButtons to be created. If I put and id in the XML, it exhibits some strange behavior with the checking/unchecking of the radio buttons. Is there a way I can get the current radio button some other way?

Comment: RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)option.findViewWithTag("RadioButton") -- This did it! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Actually ... that didn't work. Got rid of the exception, but returns null >.<

Comment: I don't get it - you have an XML layout. It *must* have a finite number of RadioButtons, unless you're creating new ones after you inflate the view which doesn't seem to be the case. Why can't you assign them meaningful IDs? And the "current radio button" can be determined by the callback code associated with toggling the button, no?

Comment: I've updated my code above to reflect that I am creating an arbitrary number of radio buttons in a loop. The XML layout has 1 RadioButton, yes, but I want to use it to just define how each should look. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way. Perhaps I should just define each RadioButton entirely programmatically? (I looked into that first but couldn't figure out how to set layout_width/layout_height).

Answer (score 0):

you want to [radiobutton.setId(INT)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId%28int%29) 
and then later get it by findViewById() to get the button.

The setID(Int) should be used when you dynamically create the button.  You can now access it later with findViewById.

Comment: This also causes the same exception when I attempt to cast with (RadioButton) option_view.findViewById(id);

Comment: you want to get the view first, mainly `View SomeView = findVIewfromId(R.id.poll_option)` and then from that view do the findViewById(id);

I also just realized your inflate() is different than what it is suppose to be. Namely, it is suppose to be [View.inflate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#inflate(android.content.Context, int, android.view.ViewGroup))

Comment: the setID should've been called when the RB was created

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you possibly update you answer with an example? (I get what you mean about the call to inflate() btw -- I'm using the LayoutInflater directly, so they have slightly different parameters)